# Regex split not working

Tags: java, regex

I want split my string using regex.

```
    String Str = " Dřevo5068Hlína5064Železo5064Obilí4895";
    String reg = "(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)";
    if (Str.matches(reg)) {
        String[] l = Str.split(reg);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));
    }
```

But, output is `[]`. Where is problem?

**Edit:** I want split to:

```
Dřevo
5068
Hlína
5064
Železo
5064
Obilí
4895
```

Then I want get numbers from this `String`.

Comment: Which language is hosting regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your engine permits look-around, split using this pattern

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/346)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I try to implement in `java`. But, I get a didn't get a good input. Look: https://ideone.com/cpf3rq